# Solubility of non polar substances in non polar solutions

Tags: solubility

From my understanding, the general rule for solubility is that polar molecules are soluble in polar liquids (e.g. water), and non polar substances are soluble in non polar liquids (organic solvents).

I can understand that when polar molecules are dissolved in polar liquids, the opposite dipoles are attracted to each other and hence the substance dissolves. For this reason, a polar liquid can't dissolve a non polar substance because there are no dipoles to attract, so it would just stay suspended in the liquid.

My question: **if both the solute and the solvent are non polar, how does the solute dissolve without electrostatic attraction? would this not also just stay suspended in the liquid?**

Comment: You might find the answers to an older question on [*van der Waals* interactions](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8691/van-der-waals-nonspecific-interaction-definition/) helpful.